# How to custom (split in two)? Ibidem

Tags: biblatex, citing

Ok guys, here comes a really tough one, so I don't need an expert, but a superhero. I need to customize my idem/ibidem to match these possibilities:

- Same bibentry, same page -> *Ibid.* [without printing the page number]
- Same bibentry, different page -> Ivi, pagenumber
- Same author, different work -> ID. and what follows

I almost got there, but the footnote 2 of my MWE should be: 2. *Ibid.*

Perhaps I should introduce a new command which basically is: if there is an ibidem with the same page cited, print *Ibid.* and kill the pagenumber.
The problem is that I have no idea about how to explain it to mr. LaTeX.

I'd appreciate very much any help on this hell issue

MWE:

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\begin{filecontents}{archivio.bib}

@article{Ben:Mat,
    Author = {Lise {Bender Jørgensen}},
    Journal = {Antiquité Tardive},
    Pages = {87-99},
    Title = {A Matter of Material: Changes in Textiles from Roman Sites in Egypt's Eastern Desert},
    Volume = {11},
    Year = {2004}}

@book{Jor:For,
    Address = {København},
    Author = {Lise {Bender Jørgensen}},
    Publisher = {Nordiske Fortidsminder},
    Title = {Forhistoriske textiler i Skandinavien},
    Year = {1986}}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt, openany]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
\setotherlanguages{latin, english, french}

%%% bibliografia
\usepackage[babel,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}     
\usepackage[    style=verbose-trad2,            
            language=italian,
            useprefix=true,                 
            firstinits=true,    
            citepages=omit,                 
            backend=biber,  
        ]{biblatex} 

\DefineBibliographyStrings{italian}{%                           Customizza Idem
  idem   = {\textsc{id}},
  ibidem = {Ivi},
}

%Idem appears on the second occurrence of the author name
\xpatchbibmacro{author}{\printnames{author}}{\iffootnote{\ifthenelse{\ifciteidem\AND\NOT\boolean{cbx:noidem}}{\usebibmacro{cite:idem}}{\printnames{author}}}{\printnames{author}}}{}{}
\xpatchbibmacro{editor}{\printnames{editor}}{\iffootnote{\ifthenelse{\ifciteidem\AND\NOT\boolean{cbx:noidem}}{\usebibmacro{cite:idem}}{\printnames{editor}}}{\printnames{editor}}}{}{}
\xpatchbibmacro{translator}{\printnames{translator}}{\iffootnote{\ifthenelse{\ifciteidem\AND\NOT\boolean{cbx:noidem}}{\usebibmacro{cite:idem}}{\printnames{translator}}}{\printnames{translator}}}{}{}


\addbibresource{archivio.bib}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

First citation\footcite[88]{Ben:Mat}\\
I'citing the same page I need an \textit{ibidem}\footcite[88]{Ben:Mat} and no page number printed \\
Now I'm citing a different page, so I need \textit{Ivi}\footcite[87]{Ben:Mat}. \\
Here I'm citing just the same author, and I'd need \textsc{id.}\footcite{Jor:For}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: What does "Ivi" stand for?

Comment: It's old italian and it means "here"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ibidpage` option can almost do that. We just need to define the two new strings and use those. You also need to patch slightly different macros for the idem.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Ben:Mat,
  Author = {Bender Jørgensen, Lise},
  Journal = {Antiquité Tardive},
  Pages = {87-99},
  Title = {A Matter of Material: Changes in Textiles from Roman Sites in Egypt's Eastern Desert},
  Volume = {11},
  Year = {2004},
}

@book{Jor:For,
  Address = {København},
  Author = {Bender Jørgensen, Lise},
  Publisher = {Nordiske Fortidsminder},
  Title = {Forhistoriske textiler i Skandinavien},
  Year = {1986},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt, openany]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
\setotherlanguages{latin, english, french}

\usepackage[autostyle,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}     
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2,            
            language=italian,
            useprefix=true,                 
            giveninits=true,    
            citepages=omit,                 
            backend=biber,  
            ibidpage=true,
        ]{biblatex} 

\NewBibliographyString{ibidemloccit,ibidemnoloccit}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{italian}{%
  idem           = {\textsc{id}},
  ibidemloccit   = {\mkbibemph{\autocap{i}bid\adddot}},
  ibidemnoloccit = {Ivi},
}

\xpatchbibmacro{author}
  {\printnames{author}}
  {\iffootnote
     {\ifthenelse{\ifciteidem\AND\NOT\boolean{cbx:noidem}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:idem}}
       {\printnames{author}}}
     {\printnames{author}}}
  {}{}
\xpatchbibmacro{bbx:editor}
  {\printnames{editor}}
  {\iffootnote
     {\ifthenelse{\ifciteidem\AND\NOT\boolean{cbx:noidem}}
        {\usebibmacro{cite:idem}}
        {\printnames{editor}}}
     {\printnames{editor}}}
  {}{}
\xpatchbibmacro{bbx:translator}
  {\printnames{translator}}
  {\iffootnote
     {\ifthenelse{\ifciteidem\AND\NOT\boolean{cbx:noidem}}
        {\usebibmacro{cite:idem}}
        {\printnames{translator}}}
     {\printnames{translator}}}
  {}{}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
  \printtext{%
    \bibhyperlink{cite\csuse{cbx@lastcite@\thefield{entrykey}}}{%
      \ifloccit
        {\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidemloccit}%
         \global\toggletrue{cbx:loccit}}
        {\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidemnoloccit}}}}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
First citation\footcite[88]{Ben:Mat}\\
I'm citing the same page I need an \textit{ibidem}\footcite[88]{Ben:Mat} and no page number printed \\
Now I'm citing a different page, so I need \textit{Ivi}\footcite[87]{Ben:Mat}. \\
Here I'm citing just the same author, and I'd need \textsc{id.}\footcite{Jor:For}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The answer works perfectly in verbose-trad2. I'm actually using ext-verbose-trad1, where the patch seems not to apply. How to apply it also in the style I'm using?

Comment: @PaoloPolesana Edit your question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/560415/35864 with a proper example that reproduces the screenshot you are showing in the question and we can reopen it.

Comment: I just edited the old question tex.stackexchange.com/q/560415/35864