# Modify the format of string Ibid. in

Tags: biblatex

The requirements of my institution impose in bibliography to use the string *Ibid.* (in italics), while the automatically generated string is not emphasized.

Using the MWE:

```
\documentclass[italian]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[style=verbose-trad1]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \footcite{aristotle:anima}
Lorem \footcite{aristotle:physics}
ipsum \footcite{aristotle:anima}
ipsum \footcite{aristotle:anima}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I obtain:

[image]

while I want:

[image]

N.B.: As you can see, just the "ibid." string is emphasized, while the "idem" have to stay unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard `biblatex` styles use the command `\mkibid` to format 'ibid.'. You can redefine it to print 'ibid.' in italics.

```
\documentclass[italian]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=verbose-trad1, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\mkibid}[1]{\mkbibemph{#1}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Italic 'ibid.']

There are some plans to make it easier to apply formatting to certain bibstrings in a language-dependent way, but nothing is final yet. You can see the current plan/idea for that at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/1028. Comments would be very welcome.

---

If you only want to change 'ibid.' you need to dig a little deeper (at the moment, this would change if something like https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/1028 makes it into a future `biblatex` release)

```
\documentclass[italian]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=verbose-trad1, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\newcommand*{\mkonlyibid}{\mkbibemph}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
  \printtext{%
    \bibhyperlink{cite\csuse{cbx@lastcite@\thefield{entrykey}}}{%
      \bibstring[\mkonlyibid]{ibidem}}}%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifloccit} and togl {cbx:ibidpage} }
    {\global\toggletrue{cbx:loccit}}
    {}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem \footcite{aristotle:anima}
Lorem \footcite{aristotle:physics}
ipsum \footcite{aristotle:anima}
ipsum \footcite{aristotle:anima}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: I saw that, when applying the suggested code, the format of string "Idem", which replaces the author name when repeated, is also affected. Actually I wish to change just the "Ibid" string. I will modify the question ASAP including this point.

Comment: @PaoloPolesana See the edit, please.

Comment: I see that the problem is addressed and solved here, so I think the question is a duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/418701/how-to-custom-split-in-two-ibidem