# Change ibid. default behavior

Tags: biblatex, ibidem

I am new to the latex world. I saw another post that describes what I would like to achieve, but I need to change one small thing.
The post I am talking about is this one: [Replace the "Ibid." string with string "Ivi" when the same reference is cited at a different page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/560415/replace-the-ibid-string-with-string-ivi-when-the-same-reference-is-cited-at)

I do not need the code code that replaces the same author with ID. What do I need to change in order to have just the ibid and ivi split?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want the exact same thing as your [linked answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/561009), but without the author ID replacement, you can just remove that code.

So you would use the below to demarcate *ibid* vs. *ivi*, as you require:

```
% All adapted from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/561009

\usepackage{xpatch}  % <- this can be moved to your preamble; refer to its documentation or search for details, if you like

% The below defines the requisite bibliography strings.
% (It goes somewhere before \begin{document}, after loading your packages.)
\NewBibliographyString{ibidemloccit,ibidemnoloccit}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{italian}{%
  idem           = {\autocap{i}d},
  ibidemloccit   = {\mkbibemph{\autocap{i}bid\adddot}},
  ibidemnoloccit = {\mkbibemph{\autocap{i}vi}},
}

% The below performs the actual patch, to segregate ibid vs. ivi .
\renewbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
  \printtext{%
    \bibhyperlink{cite\csuse{cbx@lastcite@\thefield{entrykey}}}{%
      \ifloccit{%
          \bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidemloccit}%
          \global\toggletrue{cbx:loccit}
      }{%
          \bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidemnoloccit}
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
```

Putting all that in your preamble should prove sufficient!