# How to insert "Ivi" and "Ibidem" in author year citestyle with biblatex? How differentiate for classic authors?

Tags: biblatex, citing, authoryear, classics, ibidem

For my final work, my Professor asked me:

1. to use the author year style for citing (I did `citestyle=authoryear-ibid`) in small caps (I did `scauthors=cite`), but verbose for final bibliography (I did `bibstyle=philosophy-verbose`);
2. to use *Ivi* (for different pages) and *Ibidem* (for the same page) in italic to refer to the same cited opera as the last one cited. I use `citestyle=authoryear-ibid`, but it only uses the "*Ivi*" either for citing at the same page and at different ones;
3. to cite the classic authors (presocratic ones) with the abbreviated *latin* name of the author and the work (such as *Heraclit*., fr. 39, DK).

Here i give my MWE

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%bibliography%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{filecontents*}{bibliography.bib}
    @book{2013frammenti,
  title = {Frammenti},
  author = {Eraclito},
  editor = {Fronterotta, Francesco},
  date = {2013},
  series = {{{BUR classici greci e latini}}},
  publisher = {{BUR}},
  url = {https://books.google.it/books?id=cxsbAgAAQBAJ},
  isbn = {978-88-586-4399-0}
},
@book{gianvittorioDiscorsoDiEraclito2010,
  title = {Il Discorso Di {{Eraclito}}: Un Modello Semantico e Cosmologico Nel Passaggio Dall'oralitÃ  Alla Scrittura},
  author = {Gianvittorio, Laura},
  date = {2010},
  publisher = {{G. Olms}},
  location = {{Hildesheim}},
  isbn = {978-3-487-14386-6},
  keywords = {Eraclito}
}
\end{filecontents*}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside, titlepage]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[latin,greek.ancient,english, italian]{babel}
\usepackage{quoting}
\usepackage[style=archaeologie, doi=false, url=false,isbn=false,backend=biber, style=archaeologie, bibstyle=philosophy-verbose, citestyle=authoryear-ibid,scauthors=cite]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\renewcommand*{\mkibid}{\emph} %for having "ivi" in italics

\begin{document}
Citing a contemporary author \footcite[168]{gianvittorioDiscorsoDiEraclito2010}, then again the same opera at the same page\footcite[168]{gianvittorioDiscorsoDiEraclito2010}, then the same opera but at another page\footcite[169]{gianvittorioDiscorsoDiEraclito2010}.
Then I cite a classic author\footcite{2013frammenti}, finally once again I cite the first opera\footcite[168]{gianvittorioDiscorsoDiEraclito2010}.
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

By this way I only have "Ivi" (and not "Ibidem") for any kind of citation, and I don't know how to properly cite Heraclitus in a different way.

Thanks to whoever will help me

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 0):

[Please ask only one question per question.](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864)

I will only address point 2. (You already seem to have dealt with item 1 yourself.) Point 3 is much more difficult and would definitely involve adding fields to your `.bib` entry (because `biblatex` needs to know that `Eraclito` is *Heraclit*). (I also don't understand where the "fr. 39, DK" comes from.)

For the "ivi"/"ibidem" distinction have a look at [How to custom (split in two)? Ibidem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/418701/35864).

With your style combination that can be implemented as follows.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[latin,greek.ancient,english, italian]{babel}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber, 
  bibstyle=philosophy-verbose, citestyle=authoryear-ibid,
  sorting=nyt,
  scauthors=cite,
  ibidpage=true,
  doi=false, url=false,isbn=false,
]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\mkibid}{\emph} %for having "ivi" in italics

\NewBibliographyString{ibidemloccit,ibidemnoloccit}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{italian}{%
  ibidemloccit   = {ibid\adddot},
  ibidemnoloccit = {Ivi},
}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
  \ifloccit
    {\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidemloccit}%
     \global\booltrue{cbx:loccit}}
    {\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidemnoloccit}}}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{2013frammenti,
  title     = {Frammenti},
  author    = {Eraclito},
  editor    = {Fronterotta, Francesco},
  date      = {2013},
  series    = {BUR classici greci e latini},
  publisher = {BUR},
  url       = {https://books.google.it/books?id=cxsbAgAAQBAJ},
  isbn      = {978-88-586-4399-0},
}
@book{gianvittorioDiscorsoDiEraclito2010,
  title     = {Il Discorso Di {Eraclito}:
               Un Modello Semantico e Cosmologico Nel Passaggio
               Dall'oralità Alla Scrittura},
  author    = {Gianvittorio, Laura},
  date      = {2010},
  publisher = {G. Olms},
  location  = {Hildesheim},
  isbn      = {978-3-487-14386-6},
  keywords  = {Eraclito},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Citing a contemporary author \footcite[168]{gianvittorioDiscorsoDiEraclito2010},
then again the same opera at the same page\footcite[168]{gianvittorioDiscorsoDiEraclito2010},
then the same opera but at another page\footcite[169]{gianvittorioDiscorsoDiEraclito2010}.
Then I cite a classic author\footcite{2013frammenti},
finally once again I cite the first opera\footcite[168]{gianvittorioDiscorsoDiEraclito2010}.
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

[image: 1 Gianvittorio 2010, p. 168. 2 Ibid. 3 Ivi, p. 169.]